# Variable inside a Variable, not updating

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am making a java script in which I need to occasionally change the headers of a specific request, however the token I am passing vs what i need it to be is not changing. (from what I can see) (sorry for the terrible explanation, I don't even know what I'm doing to be honest.)
Example:
`var abc23token = token1`
shortly after, in the beginning of the script

```
var headers = {
  headers: {
    'Authorization': abc23token, // SHOULD change
    'Content-Type': 'application/json' // doesnt change
  }
}
```

Then, wayyy later in the script
`abc23token = token2`
however, the request still sends as token1.
token1 and token2 ARE variables, shouldn't matter as its just a string like this

```
var token1 = "OT...Q"
var token2 = "OD...yE"
```

do i have to redefine headers? should I just ditch the idea of using a variable for tokens and use a plain string for abc23token?
please note that i don't use javascript very much and I am very much a noob at this, and I apologize if this question is completely stupid or if its inefficient to do it this way.

Comment: The value of `headers` is determined at the time the `var headers = {` line is run. It will not get re-evaluated later when `abc23token` changes

Comment: @NicholasTower so I have to redefine the headers for the token to be updated?

Comment: That's right, or you need to explicitly modify the current headers object. Eg, `headers.headers.Authorization = 'hello'`

Comment: Also note that `var` is best avoided in modern JS (it has _very_ special scoping rules that can cause fun bugs). Use `let` for variables that you want to reassign new values to, or `const` for variables that may not be reassigned new values. (and both of those obey "normal" block scoping rules)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In JavaScript, there are fundamentally two types of entities: primitives and objects. Primitives can be reassigned, but they cannot be *altered*.

Primitives include things like numbers and strings.

Objects are things like, well, `Objects` (written like `{key: value}`), arrays (`[1, 2, 3, ...]`).

For example, some primitives:

```js
let a = "hello";
let b = a; // b is now "hello"

a = "bye"; // a is now "bye", but 
           // b is is still "hello"
```

Objects, on the other hand, *can* be altered, and that change is reflected across all variables that reference that object:

```js
let a = {
    phrase: "hello"
};

let b = a;
a.phrase = "bye"; // b.phrase is now "bye"
```

It also means that this doesn't work the way you might expect:

```js
let obj = {
    token: "hello"
}

let token = obj.token;
token = "bye"; // obj.token is still "hello"
```